# How to have a debug and release build in firebase analytics for Android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I am looking for firebase to log data with my debug build and my release build separately. So when I am testing my app, I am not flooding my Analytics with non-user info. Can anyone point me in the right direct or know of a tutorial on this?

Comment: Have you seen [this blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/organizing-your-firebase-enabled-android-app-builds.html)?

Comment: Thanks, the Blog post helped me sort the issue out

Answer (score 1):

Bob's comment points in the correct direction.  It's recommended for developers to set up multiple Firebase projects to achieve isolation of data between the same app running in different environments.  This also gives you a safe place to experiment and develop without affecting your production users.

Comment: Thanks, the Blog post helped me sort the issue out.